# Dealing with vector of list of struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, stl

I read text file as:

> std::vector< std::list< struct> >

My data in the form:

```
1 0.933 0.9   2 0.865 0.6   3 0.919 0.2   4 0.726 0.5 
3 0.854 0.6   5 0.906 0.2   6 0.726 0.5 
1 0.906 0.2   2 0.726 0.5 
1 0.933 0.2   2 0.865 0.5   4 0.919 0.1   5 0.726 0.5   6 0.933 0.9
```

Where each line consist of some integer numbers and each integer number has 2 real numbers,

**for example:** 
in the first line, integer number **1** has to real number  **0.933**, and  **0.9**

This the code for scanning data:

```
struct Lines1 {
    int Item;
    float Prob;
    float W;
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Lines1 &d)
{
    return is >> d.Item >> d.Prob>> d.W;
}


float threshold;            
std::map<int, float> FFISupp;
std::map <int, vector <int> > AssociatedItem; 
std::vector<std::list<Lines1>> data;

void ScanData()
{
    ifstream in;
    in.open(dataFile);
    std::string line;
    int i = 0;

    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        std::stringstream Sline1(line);
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::list<Lines1 > inner;
        Lines1 info;

        while (ss >> info)
        {
          inner.push_back(info);
        }

        data.push_back(inner);
    }

}
```

Now I successfully stored the data in the text file, in the map  `data` which is vector of list of strcut

**BUT** I didn't succeed in dealing with vector of list of strcut (data) to do the following:

**1- create map namely** `FFISupp` **such that:**

```
FFISupp (key = the 6 distinct integer number in the data struct, value = the summation of probabilities for each number)
```

**For example:**

since the integer number `1` presents in the data sets in three positions,  the total probability for integer number `1` =0.933 + 0.906 + 0.933 = 2.772

==> The result of FFISupp

```
FFISupp (1, 2.772)
FFISupp (2, 2.456)
.
.

FFISupp (6,1.659)
```

**2- create map namely** `AssociatedItem` **such that:**

```
AssociatedItem (key = 6 distinct integer number, value = the associated items with this number)
```

associated items means, for example, the integer number 1 presents in the dataset with other integer number like (2,3,4,5,6)

```
    AssociatedItem (1, (2,3,4,5,6)) 
    AssociatedItem (2, (1,3,4,5,6))
    AssociatedItem (3, (1,2,4,5,6))
    AssociatedItem (4, (1,2,3,5,6)) 
    AssociatedItem (5, (1,2,3,4,6)) 
    AssociatedItem (6, (1,2,3,4,5))
```

**3- delete all item that has the result of sum of its probabilities  < threshold from**  `FFISupp` 
**and update both** `FFISupp` **and** `AssociatedItem`

**for example**, if two items `3`, and `6` have total probabilities  < threshold, then, I will update `FFISupp`

```
FFISupp (1, 2.772)
FFISupp (2, 2.456)
FFISupp (4, 1.645)
FFISupp (5,1.632)
```

also update `AssociatedItem`

```
    AssociatedItem (1, (2,4,5)) 
    AssociatedItem (2, (1,4,5))
    AssociatedItem (4, (1,2,5)) 
    AssociatedItem (5, (1,2,4))
```

This my try:

```
void Pass()
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < data.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned k = 0; i < data[i].size() - 1; ++k)
        {
            for (unsigned l = k + 1; l < data[i].size(); ++l)
            {
                auto  p1 = make_pair(data[i][k].Item, data[i][k].Prob);
                FFISupp[p1.first] += p1.second;
                AssociatedItem[data[i][k].Item].push_back(data[i][l].Item);
            }
        }
    }


    /*update the FFISupp, and AssociatedItem by  erasing allitems  with  <= Min_Threshold*/

    std::map<int, float> ::iterator current = FFISupp.begin();
    std::map<int, vector <int>> ::iterator current2 = AssociatedItem.begin();

    while (current != FFISupp.end())
    {
        if (current->second <= threshold)
        {
            current = FFISupp.erase(current);
            while (current2 != AssociatedItem.end())
            {
                    current2 = AssociatedItem.erase(current2);
                    ++current2;
            }
        }
    else
    ++current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please state the problem, and only the problem, without going into the solution domain?

Comment: The problem in `void Pass()` , I don't know how to deal with the vector of list of struct `data` to create `FFISupp` and `AssociatedItem`

Comment: break this down in much smaller chunks, solve one at a time, and ask again if you run into any problems you cant solve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

as i only understand what you meant in stage #1 - i'll help only it.

you code - as shown below should iterate over all the `data` vector elements - therefore the stop condition should be simply `data.size()`.

Stating `data.size() - 1` reminds me of `C` array... well. an `std::vector` is not an array, and by iterating until `data.size() - 1` you lose the last item.

I don't understand what stage#2 and stage#3 goal are.